# GORM Database.First(&tableStruct, id) without deleted_at IS NULL

Tags: go, go-gorm

When `tableStruct` have `gorm.Model` inside, how to get first record by `id` without gorm automatically adding `deleted_at IS NULL`? Is there such function?

Comment: Maybe you can try, `db.Raw("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1").Scan(&variable)`

Comment: yes '__') i guess that's the only way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a raw query

```
db.Raw("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1").Scan(&variable)
```

Answer (score 5):

After reading the source code, there are `Unscoped` method to prevent adding `deleted_at IS NULL`

```
Database.Unscoped().First(&tableStruct, id)
```

Answer (score 1):

best answer here : https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Find-soft-deleted-records

```
db.Unscoped().First(&tableStruct, id)
```